# Uniswap transaction fails with TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED

Tags: uniswap

I am trying to send a transaction using the Etherscan write contract tool at the following address:
https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d#writeContract

The method I wish to use is:
swapExactTokensForToken

And the parameters are:

```
amountIn: 100000000000000000 (0.1 ETH)
amountOutMin: 1400000000000000000
path: [0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2,0x25e1474170c4c0aa64fa98123bdc8db49d7802fa]
To: destination address
timestamp: 1602450476
```

I have tried that, but the transaction fails with an error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'.

https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x311805561520f7502befe6e1de6b49e85b9292314ac7a50c0b9fae18c84d8530

I had a look at the code fro TransferHelper.sol but I cannot find the problem.

Can someone explain why this fails?

Comment: Something doesn't add up. The error that you're getting implies that you need to first submit the transaction `token.approve(uniswapContractAddress, amountIn)` from your account. But you've indicated that `amountIn` is in ETH, so what's going on here???

Comment: @goodvibration I think the amountIn is in ETH but I might be wrong.

Comment: NM, my mistake, uniswap uses WETH in order to emulate ETH as a token.

Comment: @goodvibration I'm a newbie and dont know the meaning of uniswapContractAddress. Please tell me about uniswapContractAddress.
In my case, I deployed a smart contract (a bot). When approve in the case, uniswapContractAddress is the bot contract address, isnt it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error that you're getting implies that you first need to submit from your account the transaction `token.approve(uniswapContractAddress, amountIn)`, where `token` is an ERC20 contract at the address indicated by `path[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is the token.approve something I need to do each time I want to run the this swap transaction, or is it a generic approval for all future transactions from WETH here?

Comment: @TimothéeHENRY: You can approve a really large amount once, or the exact desired amount before each transfer. There are pros and cons to each approach, and the decision of which one to choose depends on your exact use-case.

Comment: I have sent an approval for a larger amount of WETH (https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xabc9d428bba383bf6701b573da344f344d4a07cbf9678221ac016f782df8fe95), but I am still getting the same error: https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x6d0408d36d309c445596c4c1987cb3213eebc97ab6223e14da1da317ab9a8300

Comment: @TimothéeHENRY: You did not approve the right address. Please follow the instructions in my answer, as to what address needs to be approved.

Comment: sorry I am confused. I approved the address 0xd0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c which is the one in path[0] I believe.

Comment: @TimothéeHENRY: The answer tells you to approve **`uniswapContractAddress`** using the token contract indicated by `path[0]` (i.e., by executing the `approve` function on that contract).

Answer (score 0):

I am still note very sure of

```
token.approve(uniswapContractAddress, amountIn)
```

who can extend it more?

where the token is the target ERC20 token contract?

and what the `uniswapContractAddress` express?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make the answer of @goodvibration more clear, the `uniswapContractAddress` is the address of Uniswap's Router.

This is outlined in this guide from Uniswap: https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/guides/smart-contract-integration/trading-from-a-smart-contract#approve

The address of Uniswap's Router on the mainnet for Uniswap V2 is `0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D`.
Addresses of Routers on the testnets can be referenced here: https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02